# Why equivalence $\ln(1+u)_{u\to 0} \sim u-\frac12 u^2+\frac13 u^3-\cdots$ holds for $\color{red}{u\to 0}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Taylor series for $\ln(1+u)$ is:

$$\ln(u+1)=u-\cfrac12 u^2+\cfrac13 u^3-\cdots+\cfrac{(-1)^k(u-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}+\cdots$$
and this holds for $u\in(-1,1)$ (because $\ln(u+1)=\int\frac{1}{u+1}du=\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-u)^ndu$ and the geometry series holds for $|-u|<1$ or $u\in(-1,1)$).

But when we want to use it as equivalence for example to evaluate limits we say $\ln(1+u)_\color{red}{u\to 0} \sim u-\frac12 u^2+\frac13 u^3-\cdots$

My question is why this  holds for $\color{red}{u\to 0}$ ? Is there any reason why we choose $u$ approaches to zero?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Like you say, the Taylor Series expansion is valid for $ u \in (-1,1)$, and since $0$ is in this interval, it means that $ln(1+0) = 0 - \frac{1}{2} 0^2 + ...,\ $ so you don't even need to use the $\sim$ symbol: in fact I would avoid using it unless necessary.

Comment: @AdamRubinson for example when we evaluating limits we sometime write $x-\frac12 x^2$ instead of $\ln (x+1)$. I meant the function not $x$ as a number.

Comment: Ok, but what's your point? Is your question: "Why does $ \lim_{x \to 0} ln(x+1) = 0 $ (using the Taylor expansion of $\ln)$?

Comment: No my question is why we use this equivalence for $x$  approaches to $0$ why zero?

Comment: Please be clearer. You could also use this equivalence for $x$ approaching $\frac{1}{2}$, or for $x$ approaching any $y \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I don't think we can write $\ln(1+u)_{u\to \frac12} \sim u-\frac12 u^2+\frac13 u^3-\cdots$. And my question is clear I think. I also mentioned "But when we want to use it as equivalence for example to evaluate limits we say " on the question.

Comment: Your question is not clear, in fact. I do not even know what the notation $\ln(1+u)_{u\to 0} \sim u-\frac12 u^2+\frac13 u^3-\cdots$ means. If fact I don't know what notation like $\ln(1+u)_{u\to 0}$ is supposed to represent. There is an *equation* $\ln(1+u) = u-\frac12 u^2+\frac13 u^3-\cdots$ which is true. There is a *limit* $\lim_{u \to 0} \ln(1+u) = 0-\frac12 0^2+\frac13 0^3-\cdots=0$ which is true. But neither of these seems to be what you are asking about.

Comment: The precise meaning of your equivalence in the question is given by the statement: for every positive integer $n$ we have $$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{1}{u^n}\left\{\log(1+u)-\left(u-\frac{u^2}{2}+\dots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{u^n}{n}\right)\right\}=0$$ You can prove the above is true via LHospital Rule.

Comment: @LeeMosher I agree. but I saw this notation in a book (It was about using equivalence to evaluate limits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For
$|x| < 1$,
$\ln(1+x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}
$.
Therefore
the error after $m$ terms is
$e_m(x)
=\ln(1+x)-\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}
=\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}
$.

If $x > 0$
this is an
alternating sum
of decreasing terms
so the value is less than
the first term,
so
$|e_m(x)|
\lt \dfrac{|x|^{m+1}}{m+1}
$.

If
$x < 0 $ then

$\begin{array}\\
|e_m(x)|
&=\left|\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}\right|\\
&\le\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{|x|^n}{n}\\
&\le\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{|x|^n}{m+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{m+1}\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} |x|^n\\
&=\dfrac{|x|^{m+1}}{(m+1)(1-|x|)}\\
\end{array}
$

In both cases,
the error after $m$ terms
is of order $|x|^{m+1}
$.

Answer (score 1):

Because when approximating, we usually ignore the terms in the infinite series from a certain power. So that leftover will stay as an error between your estimation and  $\ln(1+u)$. And we can only be sure of the convergence to 0 of that error when $u \rightarrow 0$ 
*Remark*:Taylor's formula also provides  a formula to control that error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my questions in the comments to the original question, I don't think I understand the original question. However, I'll provide an answer anyway.

$x \in (-1,1) \implies \ln(x+1) \color{red}{=} x-\cfrac12 x^2+\cfrac13 x^3-\cdots \quad (*)$

This says a few things.

1. $\quad \ln\left(\frac{18}{11}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{7}{11} + 1\right) \color{red}{=} \frac{7}{11} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{7}{11}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{7}{11}\right)^3 -\cdots$.  Check your calculator if you don't believe me. And this works for *every* number $x \in (-1,1)$. This is, in fact, exactly what $(*)$ says.
2. The function $f(x) = \ln(x+1)$ in a neighbourhood $(-\frac{4}{5}-\delta, \ -\frac{4}{5}+\delta)$ with $\delta \leq \frac{1}{5}$ is the same as $g(x) \ (\text{which}= f(x) \ ) = x-\cfrac12 x^2+\cfrac13 x^3-\cdots $ in the same neighbourhood: the two functions are *equal*.
3. $|x| < 1 \implies x^3, x^4 $ etc are small. Therefore we sometimes write:

$\ln(1+x) \sim x-\frac12 x^2+\frac13 x^3 \quad (1) \ , $  or

$\ln(1+x) \sim x-\frac12 x^2 \quad (2)$,

the latter being appropriate only if $x$ is very small.

So now I think I am getting to the crux of your question, which I believe is the following: I just wrote: $|x| < 1 \implies x^3, x^4 $ etc are "small". However, this is not true, especially for $|x|$ close to, but just less than $1$. So then, how do we justify $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $|x|$ close to, but just less than $1$? And I'm not sure. Like Paresseux Nguyen said, Taylor's Theorem gives a formula to see what the error is between e.g. $x-\frac12 x^2+\frac13 x^3$ and $\ln(x+1)$.